# How to do bug testing of webApp on Android Device?

Tags: android, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

My website shows some bugs on my Android mobile chrome, on laptop Mobile device screen it works fine. I already tried https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/ but my Realme phone not detected at all. What alternate I can do to catch bugs on Android browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug via Eruda Console for Mobile Browsers 
https://github.com/liriliri/eruda

Comment: @AbanoubAsad did eruda adds console in all mobile browsers???

Comment: Check the repository to be more sure

Comment: Also, you can take a look at this article https://www.browzzweb.com/2020/06/use-web-deveolper-console-on-mobile-browser.html